# Field not updating in index.html after retrieving data from server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I have created an app which communicates with the news api server and generates news .All goes well but it does not updates the content in index.html .

I am talking about the tab no. 2 only (bloomberg tab)

Code :

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <style>
            .row-content {
                min-height:200px;
                padding-top:40px;
                padding-bottom:40px;
            }

            .navbar{
                background:blue;
            }

            .navbar .container #mynav .nav a {
                color: navajowhite;
            }
            .navbar .container #mynav .nav a:hover {
                background:darkblue;
                color:white;
            }
            .navbar .container .navbar-header .navbar-brand{
                color:navajowhite;
            }
            .navbar .container .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover{
                color:white;
                background:darkblue;
            }
            .active{
                color:white;
                background:darkblue;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body ng-app = "mainApp">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse" ng-controller = "newsController">
            <div class = 'container'>
                <div class = "navbar-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#mynav">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">Latest News</a>
                </div>
                <div id = "mynav">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 0}"
                               ng-click = "activeChecker(0); change('bbc-news');">BBC news</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-click = "main('bloomberg',1);"
                               ng-class = "{'active':active == 1}">Bloomberg</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 2}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(2); change('cnbc');">CNBC</a></li>
                        <li><a  ng-class = "{'active':active == 3}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(3); change('fortune');">Fortune</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 4}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(4); change('google-news');">Google</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 5}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(5); change('mashable');">Mashable</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 6}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(6); change('recode');">ReCode</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-class = "{'active':active == 7}"
                                ng-click = "activeChecker(7); change('the-verge');">The Verge</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class = "container" ng-controller = "newsController">
            <div class = "row">
                <ul class = "media-list">
                    <li class = "media" ng-repeat = "x in result.articles">
                        <div class = "media-body">
                            <h2 class = "media-title">{{x.title}}</h2>
                            <p>x.description</p>
                            <footer>
                                <p>By --{{x.author}} on {{x.publishedAt | date}}</p>
                            </footer>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src = "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src = "scripts/services.js"></script>
        <script src = "scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controllers.js

```
app.controller('newsController',['$http','newsService','$scope',function($http,newsService,$scope){
    $scope.news = 'bbc-news';
    $scope.message = "Loading ...";
    $scope.change = function(index){
        $scope.news = index;
        console.log($scope.news);
    }
    $scope.active = 0;
    $scope.result = {};
    $scope.run = function (){
        newsService.getNews($scope.news)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.result = response.data;
                console.log('Success');
            },
                 function(response){
                $scope.result = {};
                $scope.message = "Error : " + response.status + "\n" + response.statusText;
                console.log('Error')
            });

    }
    $scope.run();
    $scope.activeChecker = function(index){
        $scope.active = index;
    }

    $scope.main = function(index,index1){
        $scope.change(index);
        $scope.activeChecker(index1);
        $scope.run();
    }
}])
```

Services.js

```
app.service('newsService',['$http',function($http){
    this.getNews = function(index){
        return $http.get(' https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + index + '&sortBy=top&apiKey=485dfa3cd11b455aba4748da6d6f2e77')
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Do you see the results on the first tab, but just when moving to the second tab - results are empty? What about other tabs? Do you see and exceptions in the console? May it be that returned results for second tab are just empty?

Comment: No results are just same as the results obtained from the first tab .There are no errors shown in the console. I have checked by using console.log that the results for the second tab are not empty ,they are having the correct values. But these are not rendered in the html

Comment: does the object `response.data` really contain a json object or is maybe a stringified json object?

Comment: No it does contain a json object. that's why the first tab works correctly

Comment: I have looked into it .And i found that main function which is defined in tab number 2 .Changes the $scope.news ,but then the get request is sent to the server ,it is sent using the old value of $scope.news. Why this happened ?? Totally confused

Comment: Looking again on the code, it is quite confusing. e.g I see you call "main" only from the second tab click, so other tabs won't do anything. Also, you have several ways to present the current tab (activeChecker and change functions)... Maybe you should simplify the code \ reduce some tabs and try to work with simple version that is easier to debug. Try to do one thing on ng-click etc.

Comment: Solved ... I was using two ng-controllers indicating the same controller within index.html .So anything that i updated on the first ng-controller ,was not reflected in the second ng-controller due to scopes